# python type error

Tags: python, string, int, concatenation, typeerror

I am getting the following python error even though all the parts are strings

```
    request = str(self.SETUP) + " " + str(self.fileName) + "RTSP/1.0";
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

the entire section of code:

```
if requestCode == self.SETUP and self.state == self.INIT:
    threading.Thread(target=self.recvRtspReply).start()
    # Update RTSP sequence number.
    self.rtspSeq = self.rtspSeq + 1

    # Write the RTSP request to be sent.
    request = str(self.SETUP) + " " + str(self.fileName) + "RTSP/1.0"


    # Keep track of the sent request.
    self.requestSent = request
```

Comment: I feel you don't give us the entire line, judging by the `;` at the end.

Comment: I see no problem with what you've shown use so far. Is there more on the line, or is self.SETUP or self.filename a property, triggering some code?  Are you sure this is the line that raises the exception?

Comment: May be a strange corner case, but did you define an own function called `str` that returns an `int`?

Comment: That was everything, i removed the ; (habits from PHP)

Comment: phimuemue has a point. Could you have overridden `__str__` for `self.SETUP`?

Comment: @StevenStangle Btw, have you tried stepping through it with a debugger?

Comment: Even if i reduce the line to:

    request = "RTSP/1.0"
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

it gives the error

Comment: Are you sure that's the line that's throwing the error?

Comment: what is `self.rtspSeq`? could it be a string?
`

Comment: @DimaRudnik it starts as self.rtspSeq = 0

Comment: @John thats the line number python is giving.

Comment: Allright... I'm taking a stab in the dark here, but could the error be raised from the new thread?

Comment: You really need a good debugger.  There's no way to tell what's happening if you can't check values at a break point or in post mortem.  You sure no property in the class?

Comment: Sometimes when desperate, it helps to break the line down into pieces to determine which part is the problem. i.e. first `request = str(self.SETUP) + " "`, then `request += str(self.fileName)`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if requestCode == self.SETUP and self.state == self.INIT:
    threading.Thread(target=self.recvRtspReply).start()
    # Update RTSP sequence number.
    self.rtspSeq = int(self.rtspSeq) + 1 

    # Write the RTSP request to be sent.
    rtps_req = "RTSP/1.0"
    request = "%s %s %s" % (str(self.SETUP),str(self.fileName), rtps_req)


    # Keep track of the sent request.
    self.requestSent = request
```